# How do I start a program automatically when I boot?

Tags: autostart, startup-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to start applications at startup automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I always have to start for example Yakuake by myself. How can I start the program automatically on boot?