# Autostart desktop applications without session login

Tags: 12.04, session, startup-applications, multiple-users

I understand the idea of startup applications when starting a session (ie [How do I start a program automatically when I boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186865/how-do-i-start-a-program-automatically-when-i-boot)).

However, I'm trying to have desktop applications for multiple users start when the computer reboots/starts.  Some apps I'm aiming for are Google Music Manager, remote desktop server for each session, etc.

How can I either have multiple user sessions launch on boot to get these apps going -or- have them launch some other way for those users?

Right now I have my primary user automatically login to start its session and related apps...

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to give admistrative rights to all those users.(i.e make them all **administrators**)

1. From Dash, search for user accounts.
2. In menu bar,click on unlock
3. enter your password(password of current administrator)
4. At the bottom click on `+` sign
5. create a new user,don't forget to give him administrator status.

now for each of them,you can add necessary programs in `startup applications` list.