# Persistent SSH Connection

Tags: ssh, proxy

I use this command to make an SSH tunnel to a remote server.

```
ssh -D localproxy:9999 -C tcx0@111.222.333.444
```

I also made a shell script using `expect` command to auto process entire process with also providing password automatically.

Problem is, I have to manually run this script to make a connection when PC starts and also, when PC goes to sleep, this connection breaks and I run this script again.

Is there a way I can make it persistent regardless of the state of machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons that can make a connection fail, even using keepalives and things like that; so you should think about a mechanism to restart it automatically.

What I would do is:

1. set up your SSH endpoint so that you can log in with a key in password-less mode: [How can I set up password-less SSH login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46930/how-can-i-set-up-password-less-ssh-login)
2. Prepare a script that do the connection in an infinite loop --- restarting if failing; [use "keepalive" nonetheless](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/keep-your-linux-ssh-session-from-disconnecting/);
3. launch it at boot: [How do I get a program to start up at boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380131/how-do-i-get-a-programs-to-start-up-at-boot)

Notice that probably you will need to use `su -c` (or `sudo`) to run the ssh as your user --- commands in `/etc/rc.local` are run as root. (Thanks @muru).

Comment: Since this is SSH, one would probably want to use `sudo` to get it to run as the user when running from `rc.local`.

Comment: @muru you are right.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/a/610379/16395

Answer (score 4):

You say you want the connection to automatically restart if it is disconnected. There is a package to do that: `autossh`. See, e.g. [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/automatically-restart-ssh-sessions-and-tunnels-using-autossh.html) for how to use it. That link also has a start-up script for making it restart on boot, though that's relatively trivial; it's the restarting on connection failure which is hard.